# Can we use two mysql queries within a single method of php class?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am wondering that whether it is possible to write two different mysql queries in one php class object method and use those results in an another class method. Here's I am trying to do (I put only the relevant part of my code here), but I think it's not working:

```
<?php

    public function sql()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";

        // Another sql
        $sql_sales = "SELECT SUM(sales) as sales FROM customers";
        // Execute this sql and result is stored in a variable
        $this->sales = $row['sales'];

        return $sql;
    }

    public function customers_list()
    {
        $sql = $this->sql();

        $customers = '
        <div id="customers">
            <div id="customers_num"><span>'.$this->sales.'</span> Sales</div>
        </div>';
        return $customers;
    }

?>
```

Can we use value of variable `$this->sales` inside another method?

If not then what's the correct way of getting it's value?

Comment: So have you tried to run your code?

Comment: Anything is possible but first of all your code has to make sense.

Comment: I think `$this` should be used in an object as a reference to itself?

Answer (score 0):

In case your code is inside a class and you're using an instantiated object :

From [PHP basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from
>   within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object

Therefore you can access any of your object properties inside its methods.

In your specific case `$this->sales = $row['sales'];` stores a value in its `sales`
property which can be used anywhere else in the object scope.

Comment: But I am getting undefined property issue

Comment: You aren't executing your query in your sql function. Use https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.query.php .

Comment: I already stated that i have written min. code relevant to my question, its not just this code on my end. the query executes and worked but can't access that variable

Answer (score 0):

We can not get variable value like your approach. Your main query `$sql` is returning the result but the value of your second query `$sql_sales` is nowhere returned. That's why it is undefined property in your method `customers_list()`.

The solution is to create a separate method to get `$this->sales` value. Then you can call this method in your `customers_list()` and access its value.